# Dynamic allocation in ksh

Tags: ksh

i am newbie on this forum
I am looking for dynamically modifying variable along the code
Ex.

```
#!/bin/ksh -f
VAR1=123456
VAR2=$VAR1
echo VAR1 # Will return '123456', good
echo VAR2 # Will return '123456', good
VAR1=azerty
echo VAR2 # Will return 123456, not good, I hope it was 'azerty', the new value of VAR1
```

If anyone has an answer or a hint to this question

Thx in advance,
Antrema

Answer (score 0):

Try nameref, eg:

```
$ VAR1=123456
$ nameref VAR2=VAR1
$ echo "$VAR1 : $VAR2"

123456 : 123456

$ VAR1=azerty
$ echo "$VAR1 : $VAR2"

azerty : azerty

# NOTE: this relationship works in both directions, eg:

$ VAR2=xyz123
$ echo "$VAR1 : $VAR2"

xyz123 : xyz123
```

---

See: [O'Reilly: Learning the Korn Shell: 4.4 Indirect Variable References](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch04_04.htm)